# Software for technical calculation of chemical reactors

Tags: software

I'm not a chemical engineer and don't have good background in it.
Just my father asked me to do something for him, as I'm a computer engineering graduate.

This is a software for calculation of technical parameters of reactor. I haven't seen it. I've just printed output of it. Fields are like following:

```
5  REM**************
10 REM***********
20 REM  Name etc.
~~~~~~~~~~~~
35 REM ********** PRODUCTIVITY********
~~~~~~~~~~~~
155 REM ***** INPUTS*******
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
220 DTB
240  DTS
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
555 REM *********** CALCULATIONS****************
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~
~
~
********RESULTS*************
DTO=75
G=543.2
Q=XXXX
XXXXXX
```

Can anyone help me to find what is the software for calculation. I'd be very grateful if you can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Years ago a colleague of mine mentioned ASPEN as a typical software (bundle) used to model chemical plants.  Despite [this](http://www.aspentech.com/core/aspen-plus.aspx) and [this](http://www.chems.msu.edu/resources/tutorials/ASPEN) lack of examples how the print-out will look like -- and I did not work with it, either.